# has_key combined with .downcase isn't working properly

Tags: ruby

I am a bit confused by behavior of downcase in this scenario if I change my code from this

```
module FunWithStrings
def count_words
    hash = Hash.new
    self.split(" ").each do |i| 
      i.downcase!
      if !hash.has_key?(i)
        hash[i] = 1 
      else
        hash[i] += 1
      end 
    end 
  hash
  end 
end

class String
  include FunWithStrings
end


p "test hello test Test wow".count_words
```

output will be proper with proper count
{"test"=>3, "hello"=>1, "wow"=>1}
If i try to minimize the code and switch it to i.downcase! in has_key function call it prints out wrong values. Not sure why.

```
module FunWithStrings

  def count_words
    hash = Hash.new
    self.split(" ").each do |i| 
      if !hash.has_key?(i.downcase!)
        hash[i] = 1 
      else
        hash[i] += 1
      end 
    end 
  hash
  end 
end

class String
  include FunWithStrings
end


p "test hello test Test wow".count_words
```

{"test"=>2, "hello"=>1, "wow"=>1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are experiencing is becuase you're calling `String#downcase!` and not `String#downcase`. If you run IRB and test this out you'll see:

```
> "TeSt".downcase!
=> "test"
> "test".downcase!
=> nil
> "TeSt".downcase
=> "test"
> "test".downcase
=> "test"
```

What happens here is that if the string is already lowercase then `String#downcase!` will return `nil`; however, the alternative `String#downcase` will always return a valid lowercase string even when the initial string is already lowercase. It's also important to note that `String#downcase!` modifies the string object referenced by the variable which may or may not be a desired result.

```
> s = "TeSt"
=> "TeSt"
> s.downcase!
=> "test"
> s
=> "test"
```

This is generally not what you'd like to do, instead you want to call the unmarked `downcase` which returns a new String object that represents the lowercase version of the string.